# Why do TextError exceptions not function properly in this code?

Tags: python, exception, try-except, ctf

The code below output's "Do not divide by zero, that is forbidden" fine when the user inputs zero, however if a sentence or characters are entered it returns a ValueError. The error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exceptions.py", line 5, in <module>
    num2 = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Hello World'
```

The code is from PicoCTF's tutorial section and can be found below:

I have tried changing:
`except TypeError:`
`print("Your input value must be an integer.")`

to

`except Value Error:`
`print("Your input value must be an integer.")`

```
num1 = 8
print("Input the number that will divide:")
num2 = int(input())
try:
    result = num1 / num2
    print(result)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Do not divide by zero, that is forbidden.")
except TypeError:
    print("Your input value must be an integer.")
print("The program keeps executing to do other stuff...")
```

however it still does not output the exception I have entered.
Am I missing something? For reference I am using picoCTF's internal web shell
Thank you all in advance for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ValueError` occurs at the `int(...)` call. If you want to handle it, you need to add a `try:` block around that code. For example:

```py
num1 = 8
print("Input the number that will divide:")
num2_str = input()
try:
    num2 = int(num2_str)
except ValueError:
    print(f"this isn't an integer: {num_str}")
    num2 = 0 # or whatever you want the default to be

try:
    result = num1 / num2
    print(result)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("Do not divide by zero, that is forbidden.")
except TypeError:
    print("Your input value must be an integer.")
print("The program keeps executing to do other stuff...")
```